# How to change a MAC Address of a PC from VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, networking, mac-address

How to change a MAC Address of a PC from VBA Excel. I need assign a random code every time the macro runs. 

**Note:** I am aware of changing it via Batch file. However, requirement over here is via Excel Macro.

Comment: Pick the right tool for the job. A Macro running in Excel isn't the right tool to be using here.

Comment: Call the batch file from VBA - done.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.